# How to add accessibilityIdentifier for UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, accessibility

I tried

```
self.searchBar.accessibilityTraits = .searchField
self.searchBar.accessibilityIdentifier = "mySearchBar"
```

in `UISearchController` but it does not work, I need the accessibilityIdentifier to be visible in Appium for UI testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to set

```
self.searchBar.isAccessibilityElement = true
```